# Angular2 ng serve an ngb build which one uses more server resources

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-cli, vps

I just acquired a vps from digital ocean created 2 droplets one a 10 $ for php restful api and another one 5$ for angular2

Now i need to make a decision on the best way to go do i run ng serve in the vps and access the app via apaddress then port or do i run ngbuild and he access the app via apache

Which option consumes alot of cpu and also bandwith assuming my app will be accessed by over 1000 views per day?

Comment: ng-serve should not be used for production : https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/5274

Comment: Thanks i see, i believe il have to do ngbuild

Comment: Also, realize that 1000 downloads of a few static files per day is basically nothing. The first computer that I bought, which had 4 MBs of RAM and a 66 MHz CPU could serve that.